# Set output device for pygame mixer

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I need to play audio files through different audio devices using pygame. Apparently this is possible by parameter `devicename` in method [pygame.mixer.init()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init), but there is no documentation for it.

My questions:

1- How to set output device for pygame mixer (or channel/sound if possible)?

2- How to list all available device-names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Pygame v2 has made all of this possible. Since pygame uses sdl2, we can get audio device names by pygame's own implementation of the sdl2 library.

## Updated method

On the recent versions of pygame;

To get the audio device names:

```
import pygame
import pygame._sdl2.audio as sdl2_audio

def get_devices(capture_devices: bool = False) -> Tuple[str, ...]:
    init_by_me = not pygame.mixer.get_init()
    if init_by_me:
        pygame.mixer.init()
    devices = tuple(sdl2_audio.get_audio_device_names(capture_devices))
    if init_by_me:
        pygame.mixer.quit()
    return devices
```

And to play an audio file through a specific device:

```
from time import sleep
import pygame

def play(file_path: str, device: Optional[str] = None):
    if device is None:
        devices = get_devices()
        if not devices:
            raise RuntimeError("No device!")
        device = devices[0]
    print("Play: {}\r\nDevice: {}".format(file_path, device))
    pygame.mixer.init(devicename=device)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(file_path)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    try:
        while True:
            sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    pygame.mixer.quit()
```

### Old method

On the earlier versions of pygame v2;

To get the audio device names:

```
import pygame._sdl2 as sdl2

pygame.init()
is_capture = 0  # zero to request playback devices, non-zero to request recording devices
num = sdl2.get_num_audio_devices(is_capture)
names = [str(sdl2.get_audio_device_name(i, is_capture), encoding="utf-8") for i in range(num)]
print("\n".join(names))
pygame.quit()
```

On my device, the code returns:

```
HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B2/4 Analog
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
C-Media USB Headphone Set, USB Audio
```

And to set the output audio device for pygame mixer:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.mixer.pre_init(devicename="HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B2/4 Analog")
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("audio.ogg")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(10)
pygame.mixer.quit()
```

Comment: I have tried this but get the following error "'device name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function." Anyone have an idea why the error?

Comment: @PeterWiley are you using pygame version 2?

Comment: I tried the script but got following error: pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.9, Python 3.7.3)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Brennofen/soundevice.py", line 7, in <module>
    num = sdl2.get_num_audio_devices(is_capture)
  File "src_c/cython/pygame/_sdl2/audio.pyx", line 56, in pygame._sdl2.audio.get_num_audio_devices
pygame._sdl2.sdl2.error: Audio system not initialised

Comment: I installed it like this on the Raspberry: python3 -m pip install pygame==2.0.0

Then sudo apt-get install git curl libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0

Works like a charm!

Comment: The updated method to list devices didn't work for me on a raspberry py 02W because at `pygame.mixer.init()` it would crash with `pygame.error: ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: Unknown error 524`. I think that's because it tried to init with the default audio device that's the hdmi one. Any other method to list devices names did not produce the same names expected by pygame. I solved the problem by changing the default sound device through raspi-config, then the above code worked allowing me to see the names of the interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Just an update on [@h.nodehi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587820/h-nodehi)'s answer for the benefit of anyone who struggled to implement this like I did.

```
Current Package Version: pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.10)

Tested Systems: Windows 10 (21H2 - 19044.1288), Ubuntu (20.04.3 LTS)
```

To get the audio device list:

```
mixer.init() # Initialize the mixer, this will allow the next command to work
print(sdl2.audio.get_audio_device_names(False)) # Returns playback devices, Boolean value determines whether they are Input or Output devices.
mixer.quit() # Quit the mixer as it's initialized on your main playback device
```

For example, My device returns:

```
['Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)', 'CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)']
```

Then, to playback the audio:

```
mixer.init(devicename = 'Speakers (High Definition Audio Device)') # Initialize it with the correct device
mixer.music.load("Toby Fox - Megalovania.mp3") # Load the mp3
mixer.music.play() # Play it

while mixer.music.get_busy():  # wait for music to finish playing
    time.sleep(1)
```

If you wish to play multiple tracks back to back, add the following code segments to the while loop above:

```
...

else:
    mixer.music.unload() # Unload the mp3 to free up system resources

mixer.music.load("Sleeping at Last - Saturn.wav") # Load the wav

...
```

If you're using a newer version of the package and some of the listed methods don't seem to work because of an `AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute {method_name}`, use [pyup](https://pyup.io/changelogs/pygame/) and search for the method in question, to see if there have been any changes to how the method is invoked. This was the main reason [@h.nodehi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587820/h-nodehi)'s code snippet no longer works unless you use an older version of **pygame**.

Answer (score 0):

Use sounddevice python package to query device names.

```
import sounddevice

devs = sounddevice.query_devices()
print(devs) # Shows current output and input as well with "<" abd ">" tokens
    
for dev in devs:
    print(dev['name'])
```

On windows 10 2020.04 these names seems to have the format

> <name> (<controller name>)

where name is what you can change, and the controller name is the display name of the driver.
E.g. my samsung tv audio output (through hdmi) name is:

> SAMSUNG TV 1 (2- AMD High Definition Audio Device)

Be aware that printing the query result itself seems to have a weird representation, for example I got for my current audio output:

> <  3 SAMSUNG TV 1 (2- AMD High Defin, MME (0 in, 2 out)

which clearly missing the whole name.

Comment: That didn't work for me. It doesn't give the exact names. Take a look at my solution.