# mixer.music.play() works in mu-editor but not in terminal

Tags: python

```
This is my code:    

 from gtts import gTTS
from pygame import mixer  # Load the popular external library
import time
tts = gTTS('test')
tts.save('hello.mp3')
time.sleep(3) 

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('/home/pi/Desktop/game/hello.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

if i run the file at mu-editor it works, but if i run it in the terminal with:

```
sudo python app.py
```

everything works but not the

```
mixer.music.play
```

i dont get any error-messages

Comment: The warning is for gTTS making unsecured connection.

Comment: @LichKing Okay, but the hello.mp3 gets created correctly?

Comment: try passing full path to `tts.save` method, but i think it's not the problem. 
maybe the problem is with the device mixer selects when you run the script in the shell with root privileges, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57099246/set-output-device-for-pygame-mixer) to set desired device

Comment: I believe your program is not being given enough time to play the sound, since chances are the mixer plays the sound in a separate thread, but the main thread dies before it even happens and it is probably a daemon thread. Try adding a `time.sleep` at the end for size

Comment: you need to add time.sleep i tried without it and the OS kills the daemon and nothing is played. if you add sleep(1) it will run

Comment: @luizbarcelos i tried but doesnt work

Comment: @tommaso i tried but doesnt work

Comment: strange for me worked. maybe the default output device for the shell is different what are you using as output device for the raspberry?

Comment: @tommaso where can i see this?

Comment: @tommaso so if i rightclick the sound icon i have av jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update: Solution

i fixed my Problem by activating SHH for my Raspberry pi.

No it works in Terminal too